# #C - simple path - directed graph - recursion

Tags: c, graph, path

I have just learnt graphs and I am trying to practice. My book from R. Sedgewick  has a challenging (as for me) exersice. I have to find a simple path on a directed graph with recursion. I have no idea where to start.
Any clues??

Comment: C? [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)? Please be consistent

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically speaking, a simple path from a starting vertex to a desired terminal vertex, if one exists, can be found by [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). This approach, which is recursive, can be implemented both recursively and iteratively (using an explicit stack).

Implementation-wise, it is worthwile to plan how the graph should be represented in data structures. Most usual are implementations where each node has a list of successors (which in C could be a `struct` to represent the nodes, having an id and a list of pointers to other nodes, which are the successors) or representation as an ajacency matrix.

Comment: I will use an adjacency list for my graph.

Comment: So all I have to do is a dfs ?